# updating a file without doing check out in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

In Rational ClearCase. I have updated a file without doing check out, after updating it asked  me that it is in read only mode still u want to make the changes , and by mistake I clicked on yes.

After that, I realised the mistake and checked out the file and then checked it in, (say version 4).
Again, I checked out the file and made some changes and checked it in (say version 5).

Now, when I am viewing the version history of that file, this version 4 is not getting displayed, version 3 and then just the version 5, but when I compare version 5 with previous version, then it is compared to version 4.

How can I make this version 4 to appear?

Answer (score 0):

The OP mentions:

> I think I have checked in this file in the branch, before updating the main branch file, and so this is causing this problem.

That is probable, and would explain why V4 is not visible in the main branch.

One way to ensure that, is by looking at the cleartool lsvtree (text), but also looking at the result of:

```
cleartool ls /path/to/parent/directory
```

(the parent directory of the file)

You can see all the selected version, and compare them with your config spec.

---

Original answer

This (modifying a file without checkout first) can only be possible in a snapshot view (not a dynamic one), and leads to an hijacked file.

You have correctly resolved the situation by a checkout/checkin.
However, if the version selected at the time of you checkout was *not* the LATEST (but version 2), then V4 would follow V2.

If you have mixed order versions, one way to get back to a stable situation is to:

- update the snapshot view, and check that you are in LATEST on that file.
- merge your last modifications (V5) to the current LATEST version

If you have a missing version, that could be because it exist in its own branch (which is not selected by your current config spec). A graphic version tree should display it (with the `-all` option).

```
cleartool lsvtree -all --graph /path/to/File
```

Comment: From http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm

Comment: Yes its a snapshot view, and the version checked out was latest... and i made changes in the main branch itself , and viewing the tree from main branch only , but still that version 4 is not displayed

Comment: and also now , when  i am creating another branch , that branch is also taking the file from version 3 , but not from version 5, while all other files are taken from there latest version

Comment: @user2028116 did you display the `lsvtree` with the `-all` option? Could you add a screenshot (or a link to a screenshot) to your `lsvtree`?

Comment: @user2028116 also, what is your config spec?

Comment: @user2028116 What do a cleartool ls does return when executed in the parent directory of that file?

Comment: i think i have checked in this file in the branch , before updating the main branch file,, and so this is causing this problem

Comment: @user2028116 Excellent, that must be it. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.